# How to separate an NSString in a file based on certain characters?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to separate the files my application opens based on the character "~". For example, if I save a text file with the string "test~test2" I need it to split the string into two NSStrings: (@"test" and @"test2"). How can I do this?

I would prefer to load the string into an NSTextView and have it look at individual letters, like so:

```
for (int integerA = 0; integerA < [textViewString length]; integerA ++) {
    [textViewString selectRange(integerA, integerA)];
    if ([textViewString selectedRange] == @"~") {
        //then split the string
    }
}
```

The only problem is that there is no "selectRange" or "selectedRange" method. Other ways are perfectly fine, but I would like to be able to make it go through one-by-one and add them to the correct string, because I may need to split the string in the text file into as many as fifteen strings.

Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT: After solving that problem, a new problem appeared: I need 12 values stored, but the NSArray says the following.

HIToolbox: ignoring exception '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (7) beyond bounds (7)' that raised inside Carbon event dispatch

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *strings = [fileContentsAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];
```

?

Comment: It's for "maybe I was confused about what you're asking".

Comment: How can I access the strings? I tried "objectAtIndex:1" but that didn't do anything.

Comment: NSString *firstString = [strings objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 1):

Wevah has already answered your question, but I thought I would point out a couple of other things for you:

1. The method for extracting a substring is called [`substringWithRange:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-substringWithRange_), this takes an `NSRange` structure as an argument. The members of an `NSRange` struct are `location` and `length`. When you want to extract a substring, initialise an `NSRange` struct and pass it to `substringWithRange:` to extract those characters:

   ```
   NSRange myRange = { .location = integerA, .length = 1 };
   NSString *mySubstr = [textViewString substringWithRange:myRange];
   ```

   Don't use this method simply to extract characters one-by-one though, for that there are other methods available.
2. In Objective-C, `==` cannot be used to check whether two strings are equal, instead, you must use the [`isEqualToString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_) method, like this:

   ```
   if ([mySubstr isEqualToString:@"~"])
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok, but when I used "==" for other things in my application, it worked. Thanks for the advise; it is certainly useful.

Comment: @Justin: `==` can be used to compare numbers, but when you use two strings, `==` will only tell you whether they reference the exact same object. If there are two different string objects that contain the same text, `==` will fail, but `isEqualToString:` will succeed.

Comment: Ok. That explains a lot of "bugs" I have been having.

Comment: If I understand right, with regard to numbers, there are comparisons where == will not be the correct comparison method to use. I.e between a NSNumber and an integer. There are ways to extract the value of the NSNumber as an int. But there is also the  isEqualToNumber which you should look up.

Comment: @markhunte: yes you are correct, I was ambiguous with my previous comment. By "numbers" I meant specifically the standard integer types in C (and their many typedefs), such as `int`, `long`, `NSInteger` etc. As you say `NSNumber` is an object, so it must be compared using the object's methods.